# Using Xamarin and VS15 on Mac and VM

Tags: ios, macos, xamarin

I'm trying to do some developing with Xamarin.  My setup is this:
MacBook Pro running Sierra 10.12.3
-XCode 8.2.1 installed
VMWare Fusion running Win10 VM using Bridged network connection
-Running Visual Studio 15 with Xamarin up-to-date with latest Stable release

I'm still just trying to get everything set up.  Originally, I was running Yosemite, so I would get the error that I needed to Accept the XCode terms when I tried to set up my Xamarin Mac Agent, but XCode wasn't even installed (my bad).  So, I updated my OS to Sierra and installed XCode.  Then, I made sure on the Mac side that my account was included for Remote Login.  When I try to connect, it comes back after 30 seconds or so that it "Couldn't Connect".  So, if I try another account in the approved Remote Login list that I don't have the password for, it comes back right away that I have the wrong credentials.  So that tells me that it must be getting thru to the Mac, but something else is wrong.

Any ideas would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To make the connection between OS X and Windows work, you have to make sure that you're running the same version of Xamarin on both.

On OS X, you need to have Xamarin Studio with the latest stable version of Xamarin and Xamarin.iOS installed. On Windows, you need to check that you have the same version by going to About Visual Studio dialog (Help menu).